# WMF format in Latex

Tags: formatting

How to  add large  picture which has a `WMF`  format  in a tex file without breaking it? 
When I convert the image it look fuzzy to me. I want to add the pic .wmf in Latex and it doesn't factor that how much space it is taking. I can email you the image if you need cause I can not post it here.

Comment: Windows MetaFile images are not supported by TeX. The types of images supported by various engines are listed [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics#Supported_image_formats). You will have to convert your image to one of these formats.

Comment: Try converting the WMF (Load/Export) with `inkscape`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use `WMF` files directly in LaTeX. It must be converted to one of the vector formats `EPS` or `PDF` or to a bitmap format such as `PNG`.

1. Use the standalone LyX tool [`MetafileToEPSConverter`](http://wiki.lyx.org/Windows/MetafileToEPSConverter) to convert it to Postscript (`EPS`) format and then use [`epstool`](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/epstool.htm) together with `Ghostscript/Gostview` to get rid of the surrounding white-space.
2. From Microsoft Office you can directly save to `PDF`. Use [`pdfcrop`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop) to remove surrounding white-space.
3. From Microsoft PowerPoint you can save it as `PNG` bitmap file, but it is not recommended because of the loss of resolution when figure is scaled.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another free and cross-platform option is [OpenOffice Draw](http://www.openoffice.org/product/draw.html), which can flawlessly import/export WMF and EMF and also export to EPS or PDF.

Before the advent of [inkscape](http://inkscape.org/en/), OpenOffice basically was the only tool that could seamlessly export vector graphics into both worlds: Windows (WMF/EMF) and Unix/MacOS/LaTeX (EPS/PDF).